# SlickGrid, copy text from Tooltip using AutoTooltips plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, slickgrid

I use objects as the data for my grid. These objects contain a text value as well as an arbitrary amount of issues.
The text is displayed in the cell and the issue-messages are displayed as a tooltip via the AutoTooltips plugin for each cell. This works fine so far.

**My problem:** I want to copy text from the tooltip. However: the tooltip disappears as soon as the mouse leaves the cell and I can't figure out how to keep the tooltip 'active' long enough (e.g. as long as the mouse moves towards it) to enter the tooltip and copy text from it. Is there a way to achieve this using the AutoTooltips plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AutoTooltips` plugin only adds the property `title`. You have to either change the code behind or add another library/scripts that generate tooltip and allows to copy text.

Check http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/tooltip/index.html.

To implement it, just add the code $(grid_container).tooltip() after the grid/rows are rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was able to get <code>JQueryTools</code> to work. I made some modifications like passing the text directly instead of setting it to the <code>title</code> first and it nearly works as desired. Thanks for that! However there is still one issue left. The <code>tooltip</code> does not pop up on the first call of the <code>tooltip-function</code> for a cell but on the 2nd and further calls. Can you think of a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You have to make it sure that the grid are fully rendered first. Chain the procedure maybe or settimeout